# How to properly use the createRoom function and callback in Firechat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I am working on Firechat integration. The [documentation](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/docs/#api_methods) states:

> Firechat.createRoom(roomName, roomType, callback(roomId))
>
> Creates a new room with the given name (string) and type (string -
>   public or private) and invokes the callback with the room ID on
>   completion.

But I am just not sure what the right syntax is. My roomName should be "test" and roomType "public". I would like to obtain the roomId for later use, so for now let's try to just log that roomId in the console. I tried the following:

```
  var roomName = "Test";
  var roomType = "public";
  function callback(roomId) {
    console.log(roomId);
  };
  Firechat.createRoom(roomName, roomType, callback(roomId));
```

Result: `ReferenceError: roomId is not defined`

Another one:

```
  Firechat.createRoom("Test", "public", console.log("OK"));
```

Results:

`TypeError: Firechat.createRoom is not a function`

Next one:

```
  Firechat.createRoom("Test", "public", function(){
    console.log("OK");
  });
```

Results:

`TypeError: Firechat.createRoom is not a function`

Another one:

```
  function callback() {
    console.log("OK");
  };
  Firechat.createRoom("Test", "public", callback);
```

Results:

`TypeError: Firechat.createRoom is not a function`

Last one:

```
  Firechat.createRoom("Test", "public");
```

Results:

`TypeError: Firechat.createRoom is not a function`

So from all that I can see the problem is that the 'createRoom' function does not exist. However, this comes straight from the documentation and everything else works (I can authenticate users and the chat window appears). See here for the full code: [How do I create chat rooms in Firechat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161116/how-do-i-create-chat-rooms-in-firechat) (I am posting this separately because I think this may be a javascript syntax issue rather than a Firechat issue, but please correct me if I am wrong).

Any idea what could be happening? Is it an syntax issue or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
Firechat.createRoom("Test", "public", function(roomId){
    console.log("OK"+roomId);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, still the same: TypeError: Firechat.createRoom is not a function

Comment: have you created the firechat object?

Comment: Yes, I can run `Firechat.setUser(authData.uid, "My name");` just fine, and it sets my username (I use a custom login). The chat window appears to be working and I can chat... I just can't use the createRoom function for some reason...

Comment: As per the documentation I am including https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firechat/2.0.1/firechat.min.js, which as you can see has a function called createRoom so I am very puzzled why it is reported that this function is not available.

Comment: Thanks but I also posted that question. Unfortunately that syntax doesn't work either.

Comment: Yes I continuously have this error in my console: Firechat.createRoom is not a function.

Comment: What _seems_ to happen is that the Firechat.setUser function does not fully run. I'm not sure though. I do Firechat.setUser(authData.uid, "my user") and it successfully sets the username. It all works. But if I try to do anything after setting the user, then nothing works. None of the functions in the documentation work (e.g. resumeSession()).

Comment: I think I found the problem, it may be related to using FirechatUI instead of Firechat. Let me fiddle with this and update when I find out more. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: OK this has been a VERY tricky thing to do but it's now finally working. I will update my other post with the way I did it. Your syntax here is correct but the class used is not correct so that is the problem. I will mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi and good day:
Create a instance of Firechat, then use the instance to create room:**

```
// Creating Firechat instance
var chatRef = firebase.database().ref();
var chat = new Firechat(chatRef);

// Creating the function to invoke
function set_CreateRoom(){
    chat.createRoom(
        document.getElementById("txt_RoomName").value,
        "public",
        function(roomId){
            alert("Succes! ID: " + roomId);
        }
    );
}
```

I'm learning how to use it the Firechat API ... I hope this answer be useful for you, best regards!